# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1660

Tags: json, retrofit2, android, gson

I upgrade my retrofit library from 1.9 to 2.3 and after that, I faced this problem:
**Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1660 path $.data[2].activities[0].at**
the part of my JSON mentioned in error is :
`{
              "doc_key": "a_S1EBp3_Z",
                    "title": "Awesome Diving",
                    "description": "If you were given one week to dive and could choose any scuba diving sites in the world with which to fill your logbook, where would you go? We asked a number of underwater photographers, writers and our readers, and got a remarkable sampling of dives that cover just about everything this planet has to offer. From the remarkable macro of Lembeh Strait to the shark dives of the Bahamas, magical reefs in Fiji and wrecks in the Red Sea, there are plenty of sites you’d expect to see, but an even greater number of surprises.",
                    "price": 0,
                    "images": [
                        "main.jpg",
                        "ryfoaYLmx.jpg",
                        "BJlMipFLmg.jpg"
                    ],
                    "has_attended": false,
                    "at": "2017-08-31T13:00:00+04:30",
                    "attendees": [],
                    "total_attendees": 0,
                    "hostel_name": "Pasargad"
                }`

I use Gson to parse Json, my model is :

```
public class Activity {

@SerializedName("doc_key")
@Expose
private String docKey;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private Integer price;
@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<String> images = null;
@SerializedName("has_attended")
@Expose
private Boolean hasAttended;
@SerializedName("at")
@Expose
private DateTime at;
@SerializedName("attendees")
@Expose
private List<Attendee> attendees = null;
@SerializedName("total_attendees")
@Expose
private Integer totalAttendees;
@SerializedName("hostel_name")
@Expose
private String hostelName;
private String address;
private Hostel hostel;
private Location location;
```

I check my JSON with a validator but I think there should be some problem in JSON.

Comment: looks like it's trying to parse the ``at`` attribute as a ``DateTime``, but got a string (obviously) and doesn't know how to convert this. Did you register with ``gson`` the right type adapters or deserialisers?

Comment: Yes, I should make a class for 'DateTime' to make it understandable. I'm working on that. thanks any way